# Passing a list of (many) conditions to an if statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have the following

```
Data <- data.frame(
  randnum = sample(1:10),
  fruit   = sample(c("apple", "pear", "plum"), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

I want to create a new column called `Data$fruit.ID` based on fruit with the corresponding ID stored elsewhere, in this case another dataframe (*but only because I don't know any better!*):

```
fruit.ID.data <- data.frame(
  fruit    = c("apple", "pear", "plum"),
  fruit.ID = c(123, 456, 789))

> fruit.ID.data
      fruit fruit.ID
1     apple      123
2      pear      456
3 starfruit      789
```

There are many `fruits` and many `fruit.ID`'s so huge `if.else`, `else`, `else` is not a preferable option.

How can I pass the fruit ID info the to the if statement?

`data$fruit.ID`

Comment: Please see the marked duplicate -- it looks like you are asking how to join two data frames on the fruit name. This would enable you to add the fruit id column to `Data` and proceed however you want with that id information.

Comment: perhaps, I will check it out thank you.

Comment: @Jim. I cannot understand your question at all. Can you try again? Your reproducible example is far too minimal. Which data frame is "huge": `Data` or `Fruit.ID.data`?

Comment: Hi Edward, really! I am sorry, I should have perhaps provided an desired output. Although the problem has been resolved using the link